# Is It Possible To Install An Enterprise Odoo Server With Docker?

Tags: docker, odoo

I was able to install an odoo server using Docker containers by following the simple and excellent instructions at the following web page: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/odoo/

I am writing to try and figure out if there is a way I can change this instance of Odoo to an enterprise Odoo server. I did not see on the previously mentioned web-page if the server is specifically a community edition. There is a section on licensing, but this did not answer my question. My best guess is that this official Docker image from Odoo is a community edition of Odoo.

**Is there a way to enter in my enterprise license key and make the Odoo server in the Docker container an enterprise version?**

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Use `docker ps` to get the name of the existing container.
> 2. Use the command `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` to get a bash shell in the container.

1. You can execute `service odoo stop` after logging in to `docker exec -it odoo bash` to follow thee steps: [From Community to Enterprise — odoo 14.0 documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/enterprise.html#on-linux-using-an-installer)
2. Or this should be the first step: [Home | Odoo Upgrade](https://upgrade.odoo.com/) using the same method described above.

Comment: Thank-you for the instructions. I am going to have to try this. I am not working on this as much but may jump back to Odoo in the future. I am trying to build my own Odoo Docker image now also so this question is not as relevant to me. This way I can start out with the version of Odoo I want and follow this book's tutorial a little closer to the letter. Thank-you for the tips.